# Javascript resolve not doing what is expected

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

In my Promise, I have following code:

```
if(a === b){
    resolve();
}
```

I expect that when a === b, Promise.then() is executed as I call resolve() when this condition is met. But it doesn't happen and code immediately after this piece of code is happily executed.

Am I expecting wrong behaviour?java

Edit:
Partial code:

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
var itemCounter = 0;
var noContentCounter = 0;
for(var index=0;index<itemList.length;index++) {
        const item = itemList[index];
        client.get(urls[env] + item['itemId'], function (data, response) {
            itemCounter = itemCounter + 1;
            try {
                if (response.statusCode === 204) {
                    noContentCounter = noContentCounter + 1;
                    if(noContentCounter === itemList.length){
                        resolve();
                    }else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                ...
```

So, if no content was found for any item in the list, I would like Promise.then to be called(to process next list) rather than executing following code.

Comment: I think you are looking for `Promise.resolve()`, however, I need more code to determine what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Please provide full code context as per [mcve]

Comment: Yes, here I am talking of Promise.resolve in Javascript.

Comment: `then` is not synchronously executed after `resolve`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `resolve`, the promise is indeed resolved, but the `then` callback(s) you may have on that promise will only be executed after the current call stack has ran to completion. In other words, the `then` callbacks are executed asynchronously, even if the resolution happened synchronously.

So any code following `resolve()` will indeed "happily execute" first. If you don't want that to happen, then put a `return` right after that call. Some would even write it in one line

```
return resolve();
```

... although that may confuse some readers of your code, as it seems to suggest that `resolve` returns a (useful) value, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

https://promisesaplus.com/

> Here “platform code” means engine, environment, and promise
>   implementation code. In practice, this requirement ensures that
>   onFulfilled and onRejected execute asynchronously, after the event
>   loop turn in which then is called, and with a fresh stack. This can be
>   implemented with either a “macro-task” mechanism such as setTimeout or
>   setImmediate, or with a “micro-task” mechanism such as
>   MutationObserver or process.nextTick

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

> A Promise in the pending status. The handler function (onFulfilled or
>   onRejected) then gets called asynchronously (as soon as the stack is
>   empty)